# Un-favorite a question on stackoverflow

Tags: support, bookmarks

How do you unfavorite a question on stackoverflow.  It seems as though once you favorite a question, then it either has the 1 in the start or the 2 in the star but not back to its original state, which is nothing in the start; or favorited.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you consider that perhaps other people starred it?

Comment: Yeah, I did.  But this one I know was from me.  It was my question and it just had a star there; with nothing in it.  I did not know what it was, so I clicked it.  Then a 1 showed up.  I hovered over that one and it said click again to undo.  Then a 2 showed up.  Then I hovered over and it said click to undo. Then it went back to 1, ect... Infinite loop. :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You click on the favorite icon.

Consider the following sequence of images:

Starting out without a favorite:

[image]

Then clicking favorite:

[image]

Notice that its at '1' now.  And then clicking it again...

[image]

back to none.  Now, I clicked it again and went to https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/213963/michaelt?tab=favorites where it lists all my favorites:

[image]

And then clicked the favorite icon there.. which removed the favorite nature from it.

[image]

And thats how you favorite (and un-favorite) a question.  I was fortunate that no one else had favorited this particular question during this testing as it would have left a little '1' (or '2') under the star, even if it wasn't *my* favorite.

> [image: two favorites]

That one has 2 favorites from other people, but not mine.

Clocks are there just to make sure I've got the order of the events right.

Comment: I guess it is possible, but it was immediate.  And it is still going it going back and forth from 1 to 2 to 1 ect ...  maybe I just do not fully understand how this favorite thing works yet.  I will read up on it again.  Thanks!

Comment: So is there a way to find out who favorited my question?  If so how?

Comment: Wait until the data.SE data refresh and poke around with queries such as http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/209390/who-favorited-me